# Android Entry Points

Tags: java, android, entry-point

Does anybody know the process of entry point generation for program with multiple entry points, specifically Android APK. I already tried to look at [Flowdroid](http://sseblog.ec-spride.de/tools/flowdroid/) and [Scandroid](https://github.com/SCanDroid/SCanDroid/), but I don't understand the terms "Source" and "Sinks" and their relation to entry point generation.

If anybody could point me to learning resource for newbies, maybe some good books, I would really appreciate it. (I already wasted a few days on this)

Thank you.

**Edit, after further reading on FlowDroid:**

Sources and Sinks have no relation to entry point generation but they are used for data flow analysis. That's why when running FlowDroid with `--nocallbacks` option, it will not generate `dummyMainClass.class`. Amirite? Or am I still wrong?

Source:

> Furthermore, FlowDroid needs a complete modeling of Android’s lifecycles and callbacks. Because sources and sinks for Android are provided by SuSi, we only have to look for entry points. Along with necessary meta information they are extracted from Android’s manifest file, dex files and layout xml files. The latter allow us to consider user interaction callbacks defined in XML (for example button clicks) and discover additional sources in terms of password fields. Because user interaction cannot be predicted statically, FlowDroid generates a special main method which considers all possible combinations to make sure no taint is lost.

Answer (score 0):

```
--nocallbacks
```

Disables the emulation of Android callbacks (button clicks, GPS location changes, etc.; this option reduces the runtime, but may miss some leaks.

What are callbacks?
From [FlowDroid paper](http://www.abartel.net/static/p/pldi2014-FlowDroid.pdf)

> Callbacks The Android operating system allows applications to
>   register callbacks for various types of information, e.g., location
>   updates or UI interactions. FLOWDROID models these callbacks in
>   its dummy main method, for instance to recognize cases where an
>   application stores the location data that the framework passes to the
>   callback as a parameter, and later sends this data to the Internet when
>   the activity is stopped. The order in which callbacks are invoked
>   cannot generally be predicted, which is why FLOWDROID assumes
>   that all callbacks can be invoked in any possible order. However,
>   callbacks can only happen while the parent component (e.g. activity)
>   is running. For precision, FLOWDROID thus associates components
>   (activities, services, etc.) with the callbacks they register. An activity
>   may, for instance, register callbacks that get invoked when a button
>   is pressed. The respective callback handler would then have to be
>   analyzed between the onResume() and onPause() events of this
>   activity only.
>   There are two different ways to register callback handlers on the
>   Android platform. Firstly, callbacks can be defined declaratively in
>   the XML files of an activity. Alternatively, they can also be registered
>   imperatively using well-known calls to specific system methods.
>   FLOWDROID supports both ways. Additionally, for malware there
>   is the risk that an attacker registers undocumented callbacks by
>   overwriting methods of the Android infrastructure, some of which
>   could even be called by native code. FLOWDROID recognizes such
>   overwritten methods, handling them similar to normal callback
>   handlers such as button clicks.
>   For finding callbacks registered in the application code, FLOWDROID
>   first computes one call graph per component, starting at the
>   lifecycle methods (onCreate(), onStop(), etc.) implemented in the
>   respective component class. This call graph is then used to scan for
>   calls to Android system methods that use one of the well-known
>   callback interfaces as a formal parameter type. Afterwards, the call
>   graph is incrementally extended to include these newly discovered
>   callbacks, and the scan is run again since callback handlers are free
>   to register new callbacks on their own, potentially requiring FLOWDROID
>   to re-extend the call graph and re-analyze until a fixed point
>   it reached. While this method is more expensive than just scanning
>   for classes implementing the callback interfaces, it delivers a more precise mapping between components and callbacks. This does not
>   only reduce false positives, but we also found it to considerably decrease
>   the runtime of the following taint analysis. Once the dummy
>   main method has been constructed, FLOWDROID computes a final
>   call graph using this method as the app’s entry point.
>   For callbacks defined in the layout XML files, the respective
>   XML file is mapped to one or more application components using
>   the respective layout controls. A button-click handler, for instance,
>   is only valid for the activity that hosts the respective button. FLOWDROID
>   analyzes each activity to see which identifiers from the XML
>   file it registers. This information is then used to create the mapping

I'm sorry, we have the same problem: there isn't a good documentation about Soot/FlowDroid. But I often find the solution to my problems by searching the mailing list.